# While setting value for dropdown in jQuery, will .change function get invoked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

Whenever we are setting values for a dropdown element, using either

```
$("#dropDownId").val(giveAValueHere);
```

or

```
$('#dropDownId option:contains("' + giveTheTextHere + '")').prop('selected', true);
```

will the .change() function for that element get invoked?

Assume that the ,change() function for the dropdown is defined and the
`giveTheTextHere` element is always present in the dropdown menu.

Comment: no.. programatical changes wont invoke the change event.

Comment: `The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This event is limited to <input> elements, <textarea> boxes and <select> elements. For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses focus.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing an element from javascript does not fire the change event. You need to trigger it:

```
$("body").on("change", "#dropDownId", function () {
    alert("Changed");
});
```

or:

```
$("#dropDownId").val(giveAValueHere).change();
```

Comment: Accepting the answer because just out of the blue, you've given me a better solution! Thanks mate!

Comment: Will your answer work with the .prop('selected', true) method?

Comment: For some reason, it's not.

Comment: @Salihdeen Can you create a fiddle to replicate your problem, I'll try to help you

Comment: Oh. I think I got it. `$("#dropDownId").change(function() {})`. This is how I have defined the .change function. Should this be modified to suit your method ??

Comment: @Salihdeen Glad you figure out the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

The change event handler wont invoke if you change value through code, although you can trigger change event after changing the value.

```
$("#dropDownId").val(giveAValueHere).trigger("change");
```

or

```
$("#dropDownId").val(giveAValueHere).change();
```